# Are the expressions "book about grammar" and "book on grammar" interchangeable?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

- A book about grammar. (A book relating to grammar)
- A book on grammar. (A book relating to grammar )

Can I interchangeably use both?

Comment: Yes, they are and you can.

Comment: Many writers and reference works consider them synonymous, but I had a strict editor who would not allow "on" to be used for "about." She considered the usage informal/colloquial. However, it appears to be very old usage and very well established. I'd allow it in almost all contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples that use **about** and **on** to describe the grammar book are correct. They both mean the same thing and are interchangeable.

> A book about grammar.
>
> A book on grammar.